# Python for ArcGIS: add a text field to a shape file, then search one field and if meets a condition, update another field

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I'm learning Python (2.7) for ArcGIS (10.8) on my own. I have this problem:

> Write a script that adds a text field to the roads.shp feature class called
> FERRY and populates this field with YES and NO values, depending on
> the value of the FEATURE field.

After trying to figure it out and checking over the internet I got this script:

```js
from arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C/esriPress/Python/Data/Exercise07/Results" # Set workspace
env.overwriteOutput = True   # overwriting outputs
fc = "roads.shp" # input feature class

newfield = "FERRY"  # new field to be created
fieldtype = "TEXT"  # type of the field that is going to be created
fieldname = arcpy.ValidateFieldName(newfield)  # to determine whether a specific name is valid or not
field_length = 3 # Lenght of th new field to be created
fieldlist = ListFields(fc)  # list the fields in 'fc', it returns a reference number of each object, not the object name.
fieldnames = [] # Create an empty list


# Check whether 'newfield' already exist or not; if not, create it
for field in fieldlist: # For each element in 'fieldlist'...
    fieldnames.append(field.name) #...add in the empty list 'fieldnames' the field name
if fieldname not in fieldnames: # if 'fieldname' don't exists in 'fiednames'...
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldname, fieldtype, field_length)  # ...Create 'fieldname' in 'fc' with length = 3
    print ("New field has been added")
else:
    print ("Field name already exists.")

​
# Search in the one field and update other field
fields = ['FEATURE', newfield]  # Create a list that contains the field we apply condition, and  the field we going to update
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor: # Setting the cursor; notice the cursor is made up of two fields
    for row in cursor: # For each row in cursor...
        if row[0] == "Ferry Crossing": #...if row in field 1 = "Ferry Crossing'...
            row[1] = "YES" #... Set that row in field 2 to 'Yes'
        else: # Otherwise...
            row[1] = "NO" # ....Set that row in field 2 to 'No'...
        cursor.updateRow(row) # Update cursor
print ("New field has been added" % newfield)

        else:
            row[1] = "NO"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
print ("Field name already exists" % newfield)
```

However, when I run the script in PythonWin 2.7.16, I get this error message:

```
Failed to run script - syntax error - invalid syntax
```

What is the problem with my script? Is it the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have 2 `else` blocks and an extra `cursor.updateRow(row)`. As a result, your `print` statement is not indented properly. Try running the following [Update Cursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

```py
import arcpy

fc = '/path/to/your/geodatabase.gdb/feature_class'

# Add field
arcpy.management.AddField(fc, "FERRY", field_type = "TEXT")

# Update attributes based on a condition
# Note row[0] is "FEATURE" and row[1] is "FERRY"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FEATURE", "FERRY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == "ADD YOUR CONDITION HERE":
            row[1] = "YES"
        else:
            row[1] = "NO"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```